# how to implement Node.js for webrtc?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I am currently working on webrtc project in which i need to make  live camera stream between two android phones. I am following this tutorial.
https://github.com/Nitrillo/krankygeek
Client-side code is working but there is problem with server-side code. Server side have 2 files package.json and app.js and i am implemented it using node.js but no communication takes place.  Is there any other additional HTML or other files are needed to run the code?

Comment: whats the error from the console when ruinning the node app

Comment: Please read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dannington-bear no error shown on console. app.js is running but no communication takes place.